# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at fibo.main(fibo.java:7)

Tags: java, program-entry-point, fibonacci

Code to Display Fibonacci Series:

```
import java.io.*;
class fibo
 {
   public static void main(String args[])
    {
     int a=0,b=1,c;
     int n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     System.out.println("Fibonaci Series: ");
     System.out.println(a);
     System.out.println(b);
      for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++)
       {
        c=a+b;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        System.out.println(c);
      }
   } 
}
```

Output in CMD:

Code Gets Executed But Fibonacci Series is not Displayed:

[image]

Comment: Your application is expecting an input parameter

Comment: You haven't passed any arguments, so I guess array args has zero length, and you trying to access args[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line
int n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
you are trying to read command line first argument but you are not passing any argument in the command line.

Try something like
$ java fibo 30

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and this works fine.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.util.Scanner;
class fibo
 {
   public static void main(String args[])
    {
     int a=0,b=1,c;
     int n;
     Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter the number of terms of Fibo");
     n=input.nextInt(); 
     System.out.println("Fibonaci Series: ");
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
         c=a+b;
         System.out.println(a+"\t");
         a=b;
         b=c;
         }
     } 
}
```